# If someone erroneously places a sticker on my car, are they obliged to remove it and, if necessary, clean any residual mark left by it?

Tags: united-states, property, traffic, driving, washington

I parked my car in some parking lot and the security mistakenly placed a sticker in it warning that it may get towed even though I did have the authorization to park my park at that location. I don't mind but unfortunately the sticker is difficult to remove properly, as shown in the pictures below. It will take some significant effort to remove it and clean its mark, and is likely to require purchasing products and/or tools for it.

This made me wonder: If someone erroneously places a sticker on my car, are they obliged to remove it and, if necessary, clean any residual mark left by it? I'm interested in Washington state, in the United States.

---

Sticker:

[image]

The sticker left marks despite trying to carefully remove it:

[image]
The adhesive is very strong:

[image: be]

Comment: @Nij thanks this other question is for the UK, I'd be interested to know for Washington, USA (and I hope it's the same answer).

Comment: The question is the same, jurisdiction is not enough to make questions non-duplicate here.

Comment: @Nij thanks, I had asked about it indeed https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/31 but no clear consensus. What if the answer depends on the jurisdiction?

Comment: Then you hope someone provides an answer for the jurisdiction you want. Add a bounty if one is not volunteered yet. A meta question from five years ago does not reflect the current consensus.

Comment: @Nij why would they write an answer for a jurisdiction that isn't the same as the one stated in the question? Sounds off topic.

Comment: Because there is absolutely no point in writing identical questions which differ only in the use of a single tag.

Comment: @Nij do people on this website typically write answers for a jurisdiction that isn't the same as the one stated in the question?

Comment: Yes. Extra space filler.

Comment: @Nij good to know that people typically ignore the jurisdiction stated the question. What's the likelihood that an answer matches the jurisdiction that in interested in, in case this is a different jurisdiction than the one stated in the question? I believe one has to be very lucky.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt See the [help pages](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"Even if you supply a jurisdiction tag, we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions – while it might not answer your question directly, your question will be here for others who may be from those jurisdictions."*. It's not that people ignore the jurisdiction tags, it is how the site works.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Before you lose reputation by bountying the "duplicate" question, I'm hoping to trigger more discussion on this duplicate closing issue first, since I agree with your reasons and disagree on this being a duplicate: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1335/3209

Comment: @DPenner1 thanks for asking the meta question!

Comment: I'm now voting to re-open. Per the [meta discussion](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1335/3209) triggered by this question, there's currently a clear preference in this community that questions should not be closed as duplicates of questions for other jurisdictions (as of this writing, the answer against duplication outscores the answer for duplication by 7; I thought it prudent to leave >24 hrs for community input before voting to re-open).

Comment: I don't think that the "erroneous" part is all that relevant. Even if you had parked your car illegally, that doesn't give people the right to vandalize it.

Comment: @Acccumulation agreed. Just added it so that people don't think I parked like a jackass.